# Show Main Categories in Sub Category page Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site. in my.domain.com/shop I have a menu showing all categories. When clicking on the main category, the page loads with a content with subcategory but the main categories disappear.

Example: I have a menu like this

```
Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 3
```

When I click Menu 1 I get something like this:

```
Submenu 1
```

What I want to achieve is when I click Menu 1 I want to get this:

```
Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 3

Submenu 1
```

The woocommerce.php looks like this:

```
$parentid = get_queried_object_id();
                $args = array(
                    'number'     => $number,
                    'orderby'    => $orderby,
                    'order'      => $order,
                    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                    'include'    => $ids,
                    'parent' => $parentid

                );
                $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
                $current_cat = $wp_query->query['product_cat'];
                echo '<ul class="product_cats">';
                foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
                    if($category->slug == $current_cat) {
                        $active_class = 'class="active"';
                    } else {
                        $active_class = null;
                    }
                    echo '<li><a '. $active_class .' href="'. 
                    get_term_link($category) .'">'. $category->name .'</a></li>';

                }
                echo '</ul>';
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo "<div class='productsubmenu'>";
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($all_categories as $cat)
{
   if($text!="shop")
            {
              if($string==$cat->name)
              { 
                //echo "hello";exit;
                $my= "active";
              }
              else
              {
                $my="";
              }
            }

if($cat->category_parent == 0)
{
$category_id = $cat->term_id;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
echo '<li class="'.$my.'"><a href="'.get_term_link( $cat ) . '">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
$args2 = array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => $category_id,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'show_count' => $show_count,
'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
'title_li' => $title,
'hide_empty' => $empty

);

$sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
if($sub_cats)
{
foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category)
{
  if($text!="shop")
            {
              if($slug==$sub_category->cat_name)
              { 
                //echo "hello";exit;
                $my= "active";
              }
              else
              {
                $my="";
              }
            }
echo "<ul class='subcategory'>";

if($sub_cats->$sub_category == 0)
{
echo '<li class="'.$my.'"><a href="'.get_term_link( $sub_category ) . '">'.$sub_category->cat_name;
echo "</a></li>";

}

}
echo "</ul>";
}

echo "</li>";
}
else
{

}
}

echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```